# Usage of herab and hinab

Tags: adverb

How are herab and hinab used in a sentence? Do they have the same meaning as hin and her?

1. Ich gehe auf die Strasse hin(ab) - I am going down the street.
2. Ich komme auf die Strasse her(ab) - I am coming towards the street.

Comment: The first one would probably be "Ich gehe die Strasse (ent)lang.", the second one "Ich komme auf die Strasse zu"... using herab is also possible in some cases but those are limited and hard to describe

Comment: The two german sentences sound strange to me, a native speaker, and the translations are wrong or at least questionable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hinab` and `herab` are more precise forms of `hin` and `her`, expressing some descent in the movement. But in most use cases they are not necessary; in your two examples `hin` and `her` are not necessary either.

You would use them for example when climbing a mountain or giving directions and wanting to be precise on whether you're ascending or descending.

Comment: Danke sehr, tricasse